# Resize a Physical Volume, resize2fs won't work with it

Tags: lvm, storage

I need to resize my PV so that I could make room for a new partition,

```
/dev/sda7 -->  belongs to Volume Group: vg0
```

`vg0` has 23g free space not allocated, so I tried

```
pvresize --setphysicalvolumesize XXg
```

to reduce its size. What's next?

I tried `resize2fs`, and it won't work with LVM partitions.

I'll have to reduce `/dev/sda7`, so that I could create a new partition, e.g `/dev/sda8` for windows system.

Comment: if you want to remove pv from vg0, then you could do with `pvmove` and followed by `vgreduce`

Comment: When writing a question, please report error messages if any. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

resize2fs works on the formatted filesystems(mke2fs), generally created over the logically created partitions(lvcreate).

If vg0 (volume group) has 23g free space, then why do you need resize2fs? You can perhaps create another logical volume from the volume group, formate the new logical volume and mount it.

If you need more room out of your existing volume group, then you need not do `pvresize` at all. Just start with resizing the filesystem that has enough free space and can sustain giving out the needed disk space. To shrink the volume, You can directly do a reduction of filesystem size with `resize2fs` but better do it on an umounted filesystem. Now `lvreduce` can reduce the volume to make more space for to be newly created logical volume and a filesystem.

If you need more room into your existing volume group, and you are probably adding more physical volumes or disks, then you need `pvresize` followed by `lvextend` and then `resize2fs`.

Better start the approach by taking the notes from `pvdisplay`, `vgdisplay` and `lvdisplay` and then muck around. If anything goes wrong, you will be sure what was the state earlier.

Comment: i need a partition for windows , but i got all the rest space for a single LVM partition.

Comment: If you need a space for Windows, use either parted, or something like partition magic to get there because all of these tools and lvm operate on Linux oriented filesystems/partitions. Caution: Data  risk, excercise enough measures to make sure the data is back'dup. BTW, I would still go with reducing the filesystem size, lvreduce, pvresize and then would go about parted/gparted/partition magic to free some unallocated space for Windows allocation.